# Python Flask - Login - UndefinedError: 'None' has no attribute 'is_authenticated'

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

Am using Python , Flask-Login,

The below line from a Flask html

```
{% if current_user.is_authenticated() %
```

throws below error in Ubuntu OS, and works fine in Windows OS(W7)

```
 File "/home/user/workspace/test/templates/layout.html", line 27, in top-level template code
    {% if current_user.is_authenticated() %}
UndefinedError: 'None' has no attribute 'is_authenticated'
```

Comment: What's your user class look like (the one passed to this template with load_user().

Comment: I get the same error after I recently updated flask and flask-login.

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out the error, I have fixed it by overriding the context processor:

```
login_manager.init_app(app, add_context_processor=False)
@app.context_processor
def login_fix():
    import flask_login
    return dict(current_user=flask_login._get_user() or current_app.login_manager.anonymous_user())
```

The reason for the error in templates is that the original context manager (from flask_login.py) is implemented like this:

```
789: def _user_context_processor():
790:     return dict(current_user=_get_user())
```

The function `_get_user` returns `None` if the user can not be found.

Comment: Looks like this is fixed in this commit https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/commit/fd82724901eaee0c4689d655f41b61ce39a7894f

Comment: 0.2.9 has been released. It includes the above commit. https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/commit/e13c35a1dd545b4b40f314a53ac491472b2d9d69